# Глобальные переменные и глобальные объекты

Tags: javascript, объекты, global-variables

Глобальные объекты вида:

```
var obj = {
    a:1,
    b:2,
    c:3         
}
```

Это также плохо как глобальные переменные?

```
var a=1;
```

Чуть-чуть по-подробнее объясню суть проблемы:

Есть программа, в ней сложный расчет, он проводится постепенно (пользователь щелкает по череде кнопочек в заданном порядке и в зависимости от получаемых результатов корректирует данные и продолжает (грубо но общий смысл таков).

Так как на каждую кнопку залита собственная функция, то функций получилось много. Каждая функция использует значения вычисленные её предшественниками и изменяет некоторые из них.

Раньше все эти переменные лежали как глобальные, чтобы быть доступными для каждой функции, сейчас решил подразобраться с этим, но не знаю как, если кто знает подскажите пожалуйста.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: а в чем принципиальное отличие первого от второго? и почему ты решил, что глобальные переменные это плохо?

Comment: "Про глобальные переменные  не читал, но осуждаю"

Comment: Ну везде пишут что глобальные переменные это ужасная криворукость, зло и вообще разгул и раздолье для хацкеров, да и тот кто будет работать с кодом может изменить их случайно, из-за чего полезут косяки.

Comment: глобальные переменные можно и нужно использовать...единственное что, если Вы их объявляете, то они не должны быть типа таких как 

var name, string, true;

Comment: _разгул и раздолье для хацкеров_ - учитывая что в браузере есть developer tools, и можно вклиниться _в любой момент_ и в _любую часть_ кода, с этой стороны разницы между глобальными и локальными переменными - нет

Answer (score 1):

У вас в обоих случаях глобальные переменные, но в 1-м случае в переменной лежит ссылка на объект, а во 2-м - число, так что это одинаково хорошо/плохо.

Если есть много переменных, которые нужно сделать глобальными, и которые описывают один объект или относятся к одной предметной области, то сгруппировать их в объект было бы разумно.

Глобальные переменные имеет смысл объявлять только в том случае, если необходим доступ к их значениям из нескольких независимых скриптов.

Можно инкапсулировать переменные с функциями создав JS класс или самовызывающееся анонимное функциональное выражение, если сами функции не требуют глобальной области (нет вызовом типа `<button onclick="myFunction()">...</button>`).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57956/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-zhulin-----).